# What is bool value?

Tags: visual-studio

I have this code in visual studio `int a = 5; int b = 7; bool something = a + b > 10; if (something) Console.WriteLine("The answer is greater than 10"); else Console.WriteLine("The answer is not greater than 10");` what is bool?

Comment: Boolean is a data type. Either true or false. https://lmgtfy.app/?q=boolean

Answer (score 0):

In what language are you programming? If it's C# then bool stands for [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).